# Who killed the co-pilot? and How?

Tags: plot-explanation, non-stop

In [Non-Stop](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2024469/) we saw that the copilot was killed from a dart like thing shot from a hole in the toilet wall. But who killed him and how did he get killed?

Comment: Well, it was most likely one of the two terrorists revealed at the end. And how? Like you said with some kind of poisoned dart, likely shot from a little blowgun kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah but they were not in toilet. The old lady and Jen were the only one to go to toilet.

Comment: Hmm, true. Well, maybe that's just one of the smaller inconsistencies this nevetheless great movie had in its overall plot. But I'd be happy to hear an actual answer for this.

Comment: @tintinmj (quote: *The old lady and Jen were the only ones to go to the toilet.*) Is that really true? It's only what Neeson's Marks can confirm given second-hand information. The old woman said she saw the stewardess Jen go into the toilet, but shortly after that either terrorist could have gone in. All anyone would need is a second, and given Marks was shown opening locked toilets with a simple instrument (pen?) there's no reason a terrorist couldn't have done it just as easily.

Comment: Also, we have no idea how quickly the poison works. The whole plot of the movie relies on the terrorists' precise assumptions of Bill's (and everyone else's) reactions, so they could've done this before the old lady went into toilet. A minor sting is disregarded by most people, and given that the second guy was being attacked by Bill, it is quite probably that the poison's effect was not  immediate.

Comment: It was the pilot being shot. I think the whole point of the hole in the toilet wall was to make Jen a suspect and add tension to the story. Strange thing is that the other guy dying from the same poisson did die after 10 minutes, which suggests that the pilot also was shot 10 minutes before. Which might make Jen a suspect again (or the old lady), would be a plot twist of a plot twist if the terrorist were working for her :P

Comment: If it wasn't for the guy who also died from a poison dart while Marks was fighting him (who also isn't explained how he got shot by the dart - another plot hole), IMHO, it would have been much more sensible to have just poisoned the pilot's food (each having different meals, due to regulations). Drilling a hole in a toilet ( as well as the blow darts) seems a bit far-fetched. Wouldn't someone have heard..? BTW, I thought it was the pilot, not co-pilot, who died.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation besides it being a hole in the movie, is that the poison darts have a very long delay time (20-25 minutes). This opens a large gap of time where the ex soldier could have used the toilet before the old lady, and shot the pilot.

The movie doesn't show who uses the toilet before the old lady, just after to make Jen a suspect.